# I am trying post a string to web service using ajax jquery but I am getting this error 500 internal server error

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, post, internal-server-error

```
` $("#but1").click(function ()
       {
         var data = { "temp": text };
           $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
             data: JSON.stringify(data),  
             datatype: 'jsonp',
             contentType: 'application/json',

             url:"https://thermostatapp.azurewebsites.net/api/updatetemp",
            crossDomain: true,
             success: function (data) {
                                    alert('success');
                                      },

             });
        } `
```

[developer tool image showing eror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0iqr.png)

the data gets posted to the server but from the callbackfunction i am getting an internal server error after 2 minutes.
server side code is

```
    'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors({
    origin: '*'
}));


var http = require('http');

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
http.createServer(app).listen(port);





 app.post('/api/updatetemp', function (req, res) {
var temper = req.body.temp;
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {

        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("unity");

        var myquery = { first_name: "sid" };



            var newvalue = {

                $set: { temp: temper }
        }
 dbo.collection("user_list").updateOne(myquery, newvalue, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;


            else
                console.log("update!1!")



            db.close();


        });

    });
```

how can i find what is causing the issue?Does sending a csrf token with ajax call would fix the error since i am using express framework?

Comment: this appears to be an issue with your server endpoint - 500 Server Error, not this posted code calling it.

Comment: it actually post the data to server but after 2 minutes on console display internal server error

Comment: even though it may be posting the data, the server may not be sending an actual success response back (or getting caught on an error), and probably timing out.

Comment: yeah exactly that would  probably be the issue.is there any workaround to fix the issue?

Comment: you'll need to debug the server code, but you can add an error handler on the client to display a more user-friendly error.

Comment: Upon looking at your server code, you probably need to return a response. `res.sendStatus(200);` it currently is not returning anything which is causing a timeout.

Comment: yeah!!thanks.This fixed the issue..